# Targeting every other nested list with CSS

Tags: html, css

Suppose you have the following HTML nested lists:

```
<ul>
  <li>
  List 1
  <ul>
    <li>
    List 2
    <ul>
      <li>
        List 3
        <ul>
          <li>
            List 4
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So a nested list 4 deep. I would like to style every other one. I know I could do something like this:

```
ul,
ul ul ul {
  color:red;
}

ul ul,
ul ul ul ul {
  color:blue;
}
```

But that would obviously only work 4 levels deep, so if they added a 5th level, it wouldn't work properly. Is there a way in CSS to automatically target every other nested list like this?

Comment: You can probably do something with an Nth child rule http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: maybe you can do something like ul ul * ... not tested.

Comment: Easier to do with JavaScript than with pure CSS. At least until there's a parent selector.

Comment: There is no way to do that in CSS. You can do it by setting a class, say at the 6th level (and 12th, and so), and thus reducing the number of CSS selector levels.

Answer (score 0):

This is straight from w3schools:

```
p:nth-child(odd)
{
 background:#ff0000;
}
p:nth-child(even)
{
 background:#0000ff;
}
```

"The :nth-child() selector is supported in all major browsers, except IE8 and earlier."

So at a GIVEN DEPTH, you can use this to style every other nested list element.  But if you need something that also takes into account the varying depths, you may need a javascript based solution which then applies these CSS3 rules.

There is also support for simple formulas in this selector but I can't say for sure how well they work since I haven't tried them, but here's the sample in case it helps you:

```
    p:nth-child(3n+0)
    {
     background:#ff0000;
    }
```

"Using a formula (an + b). Description: a represents a cycle size, n is a counter (starts at 0), and b is an offset value."

Here the w3schools page for reference which describes how to use that formula:  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: nth-child doesn't work because each <ul> is the first (odd) child of the parent <li>

Comment: This refers to number of order between siblings, not number of order in nesting level.